# import mx.controls.TextArea; not working with Flex 3.2?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

Why the TextArea class is not available for my Flex Builder 3?

Project has flex32 SDK in buildpath.  other imports are OK.

```
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    import mx.core.*;
    import mx.controls.TextArea;
```

> Severity and Description 1172:
>
> Definition mx.controls:TextArea could
>   not be found.

Comment: is my environment broken, this causes same issue: import mx.controls.Button;

Comment: mx.core.* works, but no mx.controls. ??

Comment: Is this a compile time error or a runtime error?

Comment: compiler fails.. I am now using Flash TextField() instead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you created an 'ActionScript Project' instead of a 'Flex Project' so unless you explicitly add them, some packages and components won't be available.

The easiest workaround is to create a Flex project instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use the sdk and FlashDevelop, and must configure classpaths to point to \flex_sdk_3.2\frameworks\projects\framework\src Otherwise, the compiler nor editor will find the classes.  And, the compiler throws the same error.  Perhaps Flex Builder is either encountering a conflict between classes defined and referenced in the framework.swc, or maybe the project's classpath could be set similar to FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

import flash.text.TextField;
:)